# Scrollbar on a GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

I want to put a scrollbar on a GridView in ASP.NET. I have created a master page. In this page I want a window with static height and width and inside this window put a GridView.

Is it possible to do this in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 5):

Why not put that grid in a div and add an overflow to it. So, once the grid is rendered, it will be enclosed in that div with scrollbars.

```
<div style="overflow: auto; width: 200px; height: 200px">
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1".....
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You could try putting the gridview within a div and then setting a height and adding CSS [overflow](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)style to it.

eg.

```
<div style="height:400px; overflow:scroll">
   <asp:Gridview ID="Gv1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

Comment: what if i want the paging section to be fixed?